# How to assign an incremental column name for a pandas.core.series.TimeSeries?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have `pandas.core.series.TimeSeries` with the random number column name, how can I assign an incremental name to it? (starting from 1 and end with len(pandas.core.series.TimeSeries))

I have find `s.rename` function for it but how to assign an incremental name for using lambda?

Here is the `pandas.core.series.TimeSeries`:

```
3125    1474
3126    1474
3127    1474
3128    1474
3129    1474
3130    1474
3131    1474
3132    1255
3168    1090
3169    1474
3170    1474
3171    1206
```

and I want to rename it as follow:

```
    1    1474
    2    1474
    3    1474
    4    1474
    5    1474
    6    1474
    7    1474
    8    1255
    9    1090
    10    1474
    11    1474
    12    1206
```

Comment: Can you add sample? Do you need rename columns with timeseries?

Comment: `df.columns = list(np.arange(1, len(df.columns) + 1)`?

Comment: @jezrael I have added sample

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it's a row of a data frame not the whole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign `range` to `Series`:

```
s.index = range(1,len(s) + 1)
print (s)
1     1474
2     1474
3     1474
4     1474
5     1474
6     1474
7     1474
8     1255
9     1090
10    1474
11    1474
12    1206
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

But if need assign columns names - `TimeSeries` are rows in `DataFrame`:

```
df.columns = range(1,df.shape[1] + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `reset_index`?

```
s = s.reset_index(drop=True)
s

0     1474
1     1474
2     1474
3     1474
4     1474
5     1474
6     1474
7     1255
8     1090
9     1474
10    1474
11    1206
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

This is if you don't mind the index starting from `0`. If you want it starting from `1`, call `reset_index` and then do this -

```
s.index += 1
```